# How to ensure memory consumption is not scaling with the size of the redis database

Tags: mysql, memory, redis, jedis, nosql

I am currently using Jedis for fetching my data from redis database server. I need to push this data on to MySQL. The redis server has millions of records in it. Using the below statements I can copy the data in to a set:

```
String pattern = "users*";//All keys starting with users
Set<String> users = jedis.keys(pattern)//Read all the keys in to set
```

Now my `users` set has all the records. But there may be million records that match my pattern in redis database. This will eventually consume all my memory. How can I do some thing like below

```
for(All the keys that match my pattern){    
   Set<String> set = get current to (current+10000) records from server
   ...Code to push 10K records to MySQL...
   current = current + 10001;
}
```

Or please suggest if there is an elegant approach for this

Comment: Look into Jedis' implementation of Redis' `SCAN` API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Use [SCAN](http://redis.io/commands/scan) command for that. Look at [Jedis Scan Test](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/blob/master/src/test/java/redis/clients/jedis/tests/commands/AllKindOfValuesCommandsTest.java) for examples of usage.